# Is there an event in Flex that shoots out when all the operations in a mx:state tag are done?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, states

Let's take the next example:

```
<mx:State name="sayHello">
            <mx:SetProperty name="preText" target="{this}" value="Hello"><mx:SetProperty>
</mx:State>
```

Can I somehow know when preText property has been set to hello?

Already tried with:
state->activate
state->enterState
state->exitState

and

UIComponent->currentStateChange

In all the cases above,pretext property is null, how ever somehow, later on it gets the desired value (I tested with a timer)

Any help would be great!
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is tough to say.  Most properties implemented by the Flex Framework dispatch a propertyChangedEvent.  So, in this case you could listen to preTextChanged event on the component in question to let you know that the property changed.

If this is a property you implemented yourself, just make the properties set method dispatch the event, like this:

```
dispatchEvent(new Event('preTextChanged'));
```

Add the listener like this:

```
this.addEventListener('preTextChanged',onpreTextChanged);
```

You won't be able to listen to the property change event in MXML if you don't define event metadata for the event; and most components do not bother to define metadata for the propertyChanged event.

The act of changing a state can take time.  Due to the asynchronous nature of Flex/Flash Player something like this:

```
currentState = newState
trace(preText);
```

The trace value will most likely not be set yet because the state change processing did not occur yet.  You may be able to listen to the [currentStateChange](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/mx/core/UIComponent.html#event:currentStateChange) event, thoug.  When that dispatches your properties should all be modified.